# Не работает пагинация Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

Почему не работает пагинация? На локальном сервере работает, а здесь нет.
Вот здесь она не работает - [Сайт](http://x50609w8.beget.tech/book/1?page=2)

Вот код:

```
def book_page(request, pk):
    # Get book
    i_book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=pk)
    # Get book text
    book = i_book.full_text.split()
    # On 1 page words
    paginator = Paginator(book, settings.COUNT_WORDS)
    # Get page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    # Check on int(page)
    if not isinstance(page, int):
        if isinstance(page, str) and page.isdigit():
            page = int(page)
            pages = paginator.page(page)
        else:
            # if page != int -> open first page
            pages = paginator.page(1)
    return render(request, 'reader/view.html', {'book': i_book, 'pages': pages})
```

Comment: На сервере точно тоже третий питон?

Comment: @andreymal да, во всех файлах прописано #!/usr/bin/env python3 и путь к пакетам стоит на Python3.4

Comment: env ничего не значит, а «путь к пакетам» это что имеется в виду?

Comment: @andreymal в настройке wsgi - sys.path.append('/home/x/x50609w8/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages')

Comment: Django стоит для 3-го питона

Comment: Действительно, внешне похоже, что isinstance(page, str) возвращает false. попробуйте более каноническое решение https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view

Comment: @ivan_susanin Спасибо большое, работает